# Dynamics CRM SDK - Cancel Workflow

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to find a way to cancel a workflow using the Dynamics CRM SDK.  Currently I can retry a workflow, but I am having issues being able to cancel one programatically.  Is this possible?

Comment: Are you trying to cancel the current workflow or cancel a batch of other workflows that are running on the server?

Comment: I would be querying the system for suspended workflows I know should have completed and if a retry does not work, canceling them.

Comment: the better way to handle this would be to define a logic within the workflow to end it based on the reason it might be failing... but check my answer below on how to stop it programmatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Start a workflow:

```
ExecuteWorkflowRequest request = new ExecuteWorkflowRequest()
                {
                    WorkflowId = Workflow.Id,
                    EntityId = entity.Id
                };


                // Execute the workflow.
                ExecuteWorkflowResponse response =
                    (ExecuteWorkflowResponse)service.Execute(request);
```

To End:

```
Entity operation = new Entity("asyncoperation")
{
    Id = WorkflowRef.Id
};

operation["statecode"] = new OptionSetValue(3);
operation["statuscode"] = new OptionSetValue(32);

organizationservice.Update(operation);
```

Comment: You can encapsulate this into a for each loop if required

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [Asynchronous Operation States](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309288.aspx)?

Apparently you just need to make an update call of the `statecode`.

> **Retrieving and Updating AsyncOperation States**
>
> Monitoring and updating the state of an asynchronous operation is
>   typically done interactively through the System Jobs grid in the
>   Microsoft Dynamics CRM Web application. However, you can also use the
>   SDK to write code that performs those same tasks.
>
> **Read the state of an asynchronous operation**
>
> 1. Retrieve an AsyncOperation by name using the RetrieveMultiple method or by ID using the Retrieve method.
> 2. Read the AsyncOperation.StateCode attribute.
>
> **Change the state code**
>
> 1. Modify the retrieved state code attribute to a new value according to the allowed operation states. You could also change the
>      AsyncOperation.PostponeUntil attribute.
> 2. Call Update to change the value of those attributes in the database.